# How do i print a variable defined in Javascript in Opal-rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can i access a variable in opal-ruby code that has been previously defined in javascript? For example in the following code how to fix the opal file.

## index.html.erb

```
...
<script>
  var test = "hi"
</script>
...
```

## index.js.opal

```
Document.ready? do
  puts test
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opal lets you use backticks to output any raw JavaScript that you don't want Opal to interpret, so this will output your `test` string containing "hi":

```
Document.ready? do
  puts `test`
end
```